# SearchKit: Adding Multiple Notes to Contact Reporting Not Working as Expected

Tags: search-results, searchkit

When performing a contacts search using SearchKit, I'd like to be able to get a list of notes associated with a contact (e.g. return all the notes associated with them). If I search on Notes with Contacts I can get a list, but if I search on Contacts with Notes I don't get any results. What's interesting is that it works on some older records, but not newer ones, so not sure if there's been a schema change at some point that's breaking things.

Steps to reproduce:

- Add a few notes to one or more contacts
- Create a SearchKit Search for "Contacts" With (Required) Contact Notes
- Add Note ID and Note to the report columns
- (Optionally) set the field transformations to List for Note ID and Note
- Execute the search

Expected results: A list of Contacts that have Notes associated with them, with the Notes detail in the related columns.

Actual results: No results

I tried this on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ as well.

Am I not understanding how this should work?

Does not work (Contacts)
[image: SearchKit Report on Contacts]

Works (Notes)
[image: SearchKit Report on Notes]

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the query info section it's interpreting the query as "notes entered by that contact", so the "older" ones might have been ones like that.

Comment: Thankees, that is exactly it on the results that show up, and I missed that. Is the query that's generated expected? It feels a little non-intuitive, and I'm wondering if it's a bug (which I'm happy to file), or if I'm missing how to display the notes (there's a Contact Notes Created By where I'd expect this, but not with the Contact Notes itself).

Comment: I don't know if it's expected.

Comment: It looks like somebody else noticed the same issue and there's a fix pending: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25672